# flutter - How to get list on nested map object json

Tags: json, api, dart, flutter

I'm new about flutter. I found a solution when I wanted to parse the JSON complex. I found a tutorial that can help me [see this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51), but there is a little problem with "Nested Map dynamic id". factory

like this:

```
...fromJson (<String, dynamic> parsedJson Map) {
...
property: Property.fromJson (parsedJson ['DYNAMIC_ID'])
...
);
}
```

what should I write for dynamic ID for each list with this structur api key below?

[image: see image]

Comment: Not sure what you meant. When you say `dynamic id`, did you mean `id` of each league?

Comment: yeah sir. this what i mean: 

"232" :{
"fixture_id": 232
...
...}

I dont understand whether "dynamic id": {} "the way it wraps up a list of map objects after that

Comment: Maybe what you confuses you is `dynamic` in Dart. `dynamic` in Dart is a keyword and it means a variable can be any type e.g. `dynamic x = 1`, or `dynamic y = "hello"` and it can refer to a collection such as `List`. So in your json, each `league` is just another object you can parse.